# NullPointerException while using SharedPreference in fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have to perform a task when the fragment open up for the first time ,I used shared preference for that but I am getting below exception.Is there any other way or suggestion ?

My code :

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean first = sharedPref.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
        private void gaCheck()
        {

            if (first) {
              // doing something
                sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("firstTime", false).apply();
            }

        }
```

Exception :

```
03-19 10:56:48.393    2547-2547/xyz.com.xyz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: xyz.com.xyz, PID: 2547
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xyz.com.xyz/xyz.com.xyz.dashboard.DashBoardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences xyz.com.xyz.dashboard.DashBoardActivity.getPreferences(int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences xyz.com.xyz.dashboard.DashBoardActivity.getPreferences(int)' on a null object reference
            at xyz.com.xyz.dashboard.DashBoardFragment.<init>(DashBoardFragment.java:427)
            at xyz.com.xyz.dashboard.DashBoardActivity.onCreate(DashBoardActivity.java:80)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
```

Comment: where in fragment do you have that block of code?

Comment: make sure using `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`  line inside method instead at class level

Comment: yes, where do you have this block of code in your fragment ?

Comment: Initialise you __SharedPreferences__ in `onAttach()`of fragment where you get activity instance.

Comment: Where you put this **SharedPreferences** in `onAttach` or `onCreate`

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat output, it seems you did the operation in fragment constructor and null pointer exception happened.

```
xyz.com.xyz.dashboard.DashBoardFragment.<init>(DashBoardFragment.java:427)
```

You should do the operation in `DashBoardFragment`'s `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`, in these callback, `getActivity` won't return null.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should check if you have done:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "DashBoardActivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

in your `DashBoardActivity`, if not then your `DashBoardFragment` could not get `SharedPreferences` by `getReferences(...)`.